# При клике на текст checkbox active

Tags: javascript

как сделать так чтобы при клике на текст чекбокс стал активным

```
<p class = "text">click me</p>
<input type="checkbox" class = "checkbox">

document.querySelector(".text").onclick = check;

function check(){
    document.querySelector(".checkbox"). ?????
}
```

Comment: текст и checkbox оберните label и ни какой js не нужен будет

Comment: сделайте ваш коментарий ответом чтобы я мог приять ответ